# Grails 3.0 static html in run-app

Tags: angularjs, grails

similar questions have been asked before, regarding grails 2(.3, .4). I find it strange that i could not find a way to do this, as it seems a standard use-case to me.

I simply want to serve html-pages, including their linked .css and .js (angular and jquery content) when i run grails run-app.

I want to check if my http-calls are handeled correctly on both sides - without needing to deploy a .war and configuring a database.

afaik grails run-app simply starts a jetty/tomcat - both of which can obviously serve .html pages. What do i have to do to make the grails development-tooling deploy my files?

I need to make http-requests, 
so using a different Server would violate JS-SOP, 
while deploying the .war would greatly slow down the development process

I've so far only found clunky jsonp, proxy, .war deployment solutions, or solutions for grails 2.x

I tried placing the files literally everywhere in the projects' structure (`/src/main`, `/src/main/resources`, `/src/main/public`, the assets folder and its subfolders, created  web-app directories in every subdirectory, the Init, domain, conf directories - you name it)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to load the linked `CSS` and `js` files in your static `HTML` files while keeping your `HTML` under the `src/main/resources/public` directory? For example, grails keeps my `bootstrap.css` under `grails-app/assets/bower/bootstrap/bootstrap.css`. So referencing this within my static `HTML` proves to be difficult.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the `index.html` to `src/main/resources/public`

Then add this to `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/"(redirect:"/index.html")
```

---

For grails >= 3.0.12

> Location of static resources
>
> In order to resolve an issue around how POST requests are treated for
>   REST applications on non-existent resources, static resources located
>   in src/main/resources/public are now resolved under the /static/** URI
>   by default, instead of the base URI /**. If you wish to restore the
>   previous behaviour add the following configuration:
>
> grails.resources.pattern = '/**'

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v3.0.12

Comment: I was looking where to put this pattern in grails 3.1.7. It is in `application.yml`, `grails:
    resources:
        pattern: '/**'`

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the accepted answer, you don't need a redirect. I have made able to make this work with the following config:

**UrlMappings.groovy**

`"/"(uri: "/index.html")`

**application.yml**

`grails:
    resources:
        pattern: '/**'`

Finally, you just need to have your `index.html` file located under `src/main/webapp`

Comment: This is in Grails 3.1.14, FWIW