# grails3 static picture request get 404

Tags: grails, angular6

I want to inject angular6.0 to grails 3.3.0,the detail is I have 2 project,the first is angular6.0 project for frontend,and the second is grails3.3.0 for backend provide http service.

angular project have some simple pages,just like

1. http://localhost:8080/
2. http://localhost:8080/project-list
3. http://localhost:8080/download

I get some idea from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402428/grails-3-0-static-html-in-run-app).

when the angular project finished,I run build and get a dist folder,I copy all files and folders under dist to grails under src/main/webapp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAWNW.png)

then start grails service in IDE.OK I can visit http://localhost:8080/, but all request for static pictures I get 404.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FazrZ.png)

when I run grails war script and run it use 'java -jar',I can visit http://localhost:8080/ and all request for pictures is OK,great.

but if i refresh the page of 'http://localhost:8080/project-list',I get 404 and I know why,but I do't know how to resolve it.

anybody help?thx

Answer (score 0):

some days later,I get some idea,not good but can resolve some problem.

first of all,the angular project should run with #(maybe means hash,sorry I'm not sure)in url,just do this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

it's not enough,if you just do like that,you may get some error when you run your angular project in dev env,just like https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10582, I have no idea,but if you start the project with -aot just like

```
ng serve --aot
```

error is gone.
build the angular project and copy the dist folder in to grails,and start grails project,the static pic is still not ok,no idea. when you execute 'war' and use 'java -jar' to run the war file,when you visit http://localhost:8080,everything is ok.

that's all,if you have some good idea,please tell me,thx before.